# ldap authentication using passport-ldapjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap

I am using this code for ldap authentication using passport-ladpjs module.There is no need of binding as it's already been taken care in the module. After using my credentials I am not able ton login.
After entering my credentials I am going back to failure redirect page.
Please help me in this.

```
 var LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapjs').Strategy;
    var opts = {
        server: {
            url: 'myserver:1111',
    },

    base: 'dc=domain,dc=com',
    search: {

        filter: '(sAMAccountName={{username}})',
        attributes: ['displayName', 'mail','sAMAccountName','sn'],
        scope: 'sub'
    },
    uidTag: 'cn',
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
};


passport.use(new LdapStrategy(opts, function(profile, done) {
    console.log("Ldap Strategy entered !");
    var userObj = {};
    if (profile) {
        console.log("Profile : " + JSON.stringify(profile));
        userObj.id = profile.givenName;
      return done(null, userObj);
    } else {
        console.log("User not found");
      return done('User not found');
    }
}));
```

Below is the code for routing

```
app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('ldap', {failureRedirect: 'signin'}), function(req, res){
    console.log("Login user : " + req.user.id);
    res.render('index', {data:{id:req.user.id, hash:req.user.hash, nodePollInterval:req.user.nodePollInterval}});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to the following line was not included in my code.It was rejecting the ldap TLS Certificate earlier. 
`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";`
This line fixed it and was able to access the application using the ldap server.